# How do I send commands to the ADB shell directly from my app?

Tags: windows, shell, python-3.x, adb, popen

I want to send commands in the ADB shell itself as if i had done the following in cmd.

```
    >adb shell
    shell@:/ <command>
```

I am using python 3.4 on a windows 7 OS 64bit machine. I can send one-line shell commands simply using subprocess.getoutput such as:

```
subprocess.getoutput ('adb pull /storage/sdcard0/file.txt')
```

as long as the adb commands themselves are recognized by ADB specifically, such as pull and push, however there are other commands such as grep that need to be run IN the shell, like above, since they are not recognized by adb. for example, the following line will not work:

```
subprocess.getoutput ('adb shell ls -l | grep ...')
```

To enter the commands in the shell I thought I needed some kind of expect library as that is what 'everyone' suggests, however pexpect, wexpect, and winexpect all failed to work. they were written for python 2 and after being ported to python 3 and my going through the .py files by hand, even those tweaked for windows, nothing was working - each of them for different reasons.

how can i send the input i want to the adb shell directly?

Answer (score 0):

If none of the already recommended shortcuts work for you you can still go the 'regular' way using 'subprocess.Popen' for entering commands in the adb shell with Popen:

```
    cmd1 = 'adb shell'
    cmd2 = 'ls -l | grep ...'
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1.split(), stdin=PIPE)
    time.sleep(1)
    p.stdin.write(cmd2.encode('utf-8'))
    p.stdin.write('\n'.encode('utf-8'))
    p.stdin.flush()
    time.sleep(3)
    p.kill()
```

Some things to remember:

1. even though you import subprocess you still need to invoke subprocess.Popen
2. sending cmd1 as a string or as items in a list should work too but '.split()' does the trick and is easier on the eyes
3. since you only specidfied you want to enter input to the shell you only need stdin=PIPE. stdout would only be necessary if you wanted to receive output from the shell
4. time.sleep(1) isn't really necessary, however since many complained about input issues being faster or slower in python 2 vs 3 consider maybe using it. 'they' might have been using versions of 'expect' that need the shell's reply first. this code also worked when i tested it with simply swapping out and in the process with time.sleep(0)
5. stdin.write will return an error if the input is not encoded properly. python's default is unicode. entering by binary did not work for me in my tests like this "b\ls ..." but .encode() worked. dont forget the endline!
6. if you use .encode() there is a worry that the line might not get sent properly, so to be sure it might be good to include a flush().
7. time.sleep(3) is completely uneccesary, but if your command takes a long time to execute (eg a regressive search through the entire device piped out to a txt file on the memory card) maybe give it some extra time before killing anyhting.
8. remember to kill. if you didnt kill it, the pipe may remain open, and even after exiting the test app on the console the next commend still went to the shell even though the prompt appearsed to be my regular cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Amichai, I have to start with pointing out that your own "solution" is pretty awful. And your explanation makes it even worse. Doing all those unnecessary things just because you do not understand how shell (here I mean your PC's OS shell, not `adb`) command parsing works.

When all you needed was just this one command:

```
subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'shell', 'ls /storage/sdcard0 | grep ...']).decode('utf-8')
```